# Firefox only launches through terminal

Tags: firefox, kde

When I try to launch firefox nothing happend. If i try to launch firefox using the terminal it will boot with the following output:

```
$ firefox

Gtk-Message: 14:15:43.815: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"

(firefox:11586): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:15:43.865: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:21: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/roy/snap/firefox/3131/.config/gtk-3.0/colors.css: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: 14:15:43.881: Failed to load module "window-decorations-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 14:15:43.881: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
[Parent 11586, Main Thread] WARNING: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Connection refused: 'glib warning', file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:167

(firefox:11586): IBUS-WARNING **: 14:15:44.049: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Searching online people where taling about installing xapp. doing `sudo apt install xapp` gives the following output:

```
$ sudo apt install xapp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package xapp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  xapp-sn-watcher libxapp-gtk3-module

E: Package 'xapp' has no installation candidate
```

Both the xapp-sn-watcher and libxapp-gtk3-module are already installed, i did install `python3-xapp` but that hasn't fixed anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstall Firefox, but with the deb package instead of the snap package:

[How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/732775)

In my experience the snap package has some weird bugs and switching away from that has helped some. Good luck.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Link didn't work but removing the snap and installing using apt worked.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/1735303